# How do I use a left-join and non-left-join on more than 2 tables using linq

Tags: c#, linq

I am trying to join 3 tables into a specific model using linq but I am getting incorrect results.

### With my code below:

```cs
var filteredEmployees = _employeesRepository.GetAll(); //TODO: Filter

var filteredSchedules = _schedulesRepository.GetAll(); //TODO: Filter

var filteredPunches = _punchesRepository.GetAll(); //TODO: Filter

var innerGroupJoinQuery =
        from allEmployees in filteredEmployees
        join allSchedule in filteredSchedules on allEmployees.FileNumber equals allSchedule.FileNumber
        join allPunches in filteredPunches on allSchedule.Id equals allPunches.ScheduleId
        select new {Employee = allEmployees, Schedule = allSchedule, Punches = allPunches}; <--  this part doesnt seem correct to me

var innerGroupJoinQueryList = innerGroupJoinQuery.ToList();

var inner2 = innerGroupJoinQueryList
        .GroupBy(g => g.Employee)
        .Select(s => new JanusWeeklyOverviewDto()
        {
                Employee = ObjectMapper.Map<EmployeesDto>(s.Key),
                ScheduleAndPunches = s.Select(s2 => new ScheduleAndPunchesDto()
                {
                        Schedule = ObjectMapper.Map<SchedulesDto>(s2.Schedule),
                        Punches = s.Where(w => w.Schedule.Id == w.Punches.ScheduleId).Select(s3 => ObjectMapper.Map<PunchesDto>(s3.Punches)),
                })
        })
        .ToList();
```

**Problem 1**:

In the `ScheduleAndPunches` model, there is exactly 7 `Schedule` record for every `Employee` between a given week range (Sunday 2/14 to Saturday 2/20) but it currently only returns records that have a `Punch` entry.

**Q1**: How would I change my code so that it does a left-join and pulls all 7 `Schedule` records and the `Punch` record associated (if any).

**Problem 2**:

In the `ScheduleAndPunches` model, punches returns all `Punches` record, ignoring the `Schedule.Id` its associated with.

**Q2**: How would I change my code so that it pulls all `Punches` records based on the `Schedule.Id`.

### The SQL equivalent query would look like this:

[image]

```sql
SELECT TOP (100) PERCENT
    Janus.Employees.FileNumber,
    Janus.Employees.HomeDepartment,
    Janus.Employees.LastName,
    Janus.Employees.FirstName,
    Janus.Schedules.Id AS ScheduleId,
    Janus.Schedules.ScheduleDate,
    Janus.Schedules.EndDate,
    Janus.Schedules.StartTime,
    Janus.Schedules.EndTime,
    Janus.Schedules.ForcedLabor,
    Janus.Punches.Id   AS PunchId,
    Janus.Punches.TimeStamp,
    Janus.Punches.OriginalTimeStamp,
    Janus.Punches.CurrentState,
    Janus.Punches.WasOverridden,
    Janus.Punches.OverrideId,
    Janus.Punches.EnteredBy,
    Janus.Punches.Comments
FROM
    Janus.Employees
        INNER JOIN      Janus.Schedules
                        ON Janus.Employees.FileNumber = Janus.Schedules.FileNumber
        LEFT OUTER JOIN Janus.Punches
                        ON Janus.Schedules.Id = Janus.Punches.ScheduleId -- AND Janus.Schedule.FileNumber = Janus.Punches.FileNumber
WHERE
      (Janus.Employees.FileNumber = '8095')
  AND (Janus.Schedules.ScheduleDate BETWEEN '20210214' AND '20210220')
ORDER BY
    Janus.Employees.FileNumber,
    Janus.Schedules.ScheduleDate,
    Janus.Punches.TimeStamp DESC
```

### The expected model to return looks like this:

```cs
public class JanusWeeklyOverviewDto
{
    public EmployeesDto Employee { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<ScheduleAndPunchesDto> ScheduleAndPunches { get; set; }
}

public class ScheduleAndPunchesDto
{
    public SchedulesDto Schedule { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<PunchesDto> Punches { get; set; }
}

public class EmployeesDto  : EntityDto
{
    public string FileNumber { get; set; }

    public string LastName { get; set; }

    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    public string BadgeNumber { get; set; }

    public DateTime? HiredDate { get; set; }

    public DateTime? DateOfBirth { get; set; }

    public decimal? Rate { get; set; }

    public string RateType { get; set; }

    public string HomeDepartment { get; set; }

    public string Status { get; set; }

    public int? LunchRule { get; set; }

    public DateTime? EffectiveDate { get; set; }

    public string Comments { get; set; }

    public string CurrentState { get; set; }

    public string OvertimeState { get; set; }

    public DateTime? TerminationDate { get; set; }

    public string Role { get; set; }

    public string Profile { get; set; }

    public byte[] Photo { get; set; }

    public int? PhotoFileId { get; set; }
}

public class SchedulesDto : EntityDto
{
    public string FileNumber { get; set; }

    public DateTime? ScheduleDate { get; set; }

    public DateTime? StartTime { get; set; }

    public DateTime? EndTime { get; set; }

    public DateTime? EndDate { get; set; }

    public string ForcedLabor { get; set; }
}

public class PunchesDto : EntityDto
{
    public string FileNumber { get; set; }

    public DateTime TimeStamp { get; set; }
    public DateTime OriginalTimeStamp { get; set; }

    public string CurrentState { get; set; }

    public string WasOverridden { get; set; }

    public string OverrideId { get; set; }

    public string EnteredBy { get; set; }

    public string Comments { get; set; }

    public byte[] EmployeePhoto { get; set; }

    public int? EmployeePhotoFileId { get; set; }

    public byte[] ManagerPhoto { get; set; }

    public int? ManagerPhotoFileId { get; set; }

    public int? ScheduleId { get; set; }
    
    public string AppVersion { get; set; }
    
    public bool DeviceWasOffline { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've tried using the method syntax because i'm not to great at the query syntax:

```
var query = filteredEmployees
    .GroupJoin(filteredSchedules, e => e.FileNumber, s => s.FileNumber, (e, s) => new { Employee = e, Schedule = s})
    .SelectMany(o => o.Schedule.DefaultIfEmpty(), (l, r) => new { l.Employee, Schedule = r })

    .GroupJoin(filteredPunches, t => t.Schedule.Id, p => p.ScheduleId, (t, p) => new { t.Employee, t.Schedule, Punch = p })
    .SelectMany(o => o.Punch.DefaultIfEmpty(), (l, r) => new { l.Employee, l.Schedule, Punch = r })
    
    .Select(x => new {
        FileNumber = x.Employee.FileNumber,
        Name = x.Employee.FirstName,
        ScheduleId = x.Schedule.Id,
        StartTime = x.Schedule.StartTime,
        EndTime = x.Schedule.EndDate,
        ActualPunchTime = x.Punch?.TimeStamp
    })
    .ToList();
```

I've cut down the required amount of fileds for testing, but as far as i can tell it's what your after:

```
 ToString()       : { FileNumber = 12345, Name = Lee, ScheduleId = 1, StartTime = 02/19/2021 00:00:00, EndTime = 02/19/2021 09:00:00, ActualPunchTime =  }
 ToString()       : { FileNumber = 12345, Name = Lee, ScheduleId = 2, StartTime = 02/18/2021 00:00:00, EndTime = 02/19/2021 00:00:00, ActualPunchTime = 02/19/2021 21:08:48 }
 ToString()       : { FileNumber = 12345, Name = Lee, ScheduleId = 3, StartTime = 02/17/2021 00:00:00, EndTime = 02/18/2021 00:00:00, ActualPunchTime =  }
 ToString()       : { FileNumber = 12345, Name = Lee, ScheduleId = 4, StartTime = 02/17/2021 00:00:00, EndTime = 02/18/2021 00:00:00, ActualPunchTime =  }
 ToString()       : { FileNumber = 12345, Name = Lee, ScheduleId = 5, StartTime = 02/17/2021 00:00:00, EndTime = 02/18/2021 00:00:00, ActualPunchTime =  }
 ToString()       : { FileNumber = 12346, Name = Bob, ScheduleId = 6, StartTime = 02/17/2021 00:00:00, EndTime = 02/18/2021 00:00:00, ActualPunchTime = 02/19/2021 21:08:48 }
```

My Test data:

```
    var filteredEmployees = new List<Employee> { 
    new Employee 
    {
        Id = 1,
        FileNumber = "12345",
        FirstName = "Lee",
    },
    new Employee 
    {
        Id = 2,
        FileNumber = "12346",
        FirstName = "Bob",
    } 
};

var filteredSchedules = new List<Schedule> 
{
    new Schedule {
        Id = 1,
        FileNumber = "12345",
        StartTime = DateTime.Now.Date,
        EndDate = DateTime.Now.Date.AddHours(9)
    },
    new Schedule {
        Id = 2,
        FileNumber = "12345",
        StartTime = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1).Date,
        EndDate = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1).AddHours(9).Date
    },
    new Schedule {
        Id = 3,
        FileNumber = "12345",
        StartTime = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-2).Date,
        EndDate = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-2).AddHours(9).Date
    },
    new Schedule {
        Id = 4,
        FileNumber = "12345",
        StartTime = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-2).Date,
        EndDate = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-2).AddHours(9).Date
    },
    new Schedule {
        Id = 5,
        FileNumber = "12345",
        StartTime = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-2).Date,
        EndDate = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-2).AddHours(9).Date
    },
    new Schedule {
        Id = 6,
        FileNumber = "12346",
        StartTime = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-2).Date,
        EndDate = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-2).AddHours(9).Date
    },
};
var filteredPunches = new List<Punches> 
{
    new Punches {
        Id = 1,
        ScheduleId = 2,
        TimeStamp = DateTime.Now
    },
    new Punches {
        Id = 2,
        ScheduleId = 6,
        TimeStamp = DateTime.Now
    }
};
```

You can view my fiddle here: https://dotnetfiddle.net/jpWRh8

Comment: I tend to avoid the method query for `Joins` because it think they look messy thats why i went the syntax route. The code you provided solves my initial problem so i will mark it as accepted, however i am having issues re-writing the `select` method to build the `JanusWeeklyOverviewDto` model. Your code selects a flat model, i need the results to be 3d. Im just not sure how to populate `IEnumerable<ScheduleAndPunchesDto>` like i have done in `inner2` property in the code i provided.

Comment: Ok, I figured it out. I broke the query into 2 parts. First part gets the `Schedules` and `Punches`. Second part joins the results to `Employees`